# Why is this circular template instantiation legal?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, circular-reference

I don't understand what the compiler's doing here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// non-default-constructable struct
struct X
{
    X(int v) : x(v) {}
    const int x;
};

template< typename T>
struct A
{
    static const X a;
};

// trigger a compiler error if we try to instantiate the default template
template< typename T >
const X A<T>::a;


template<>
struct A<int>
{
    static const X a;
};

template<>
struct A<float>
{
    static const X a;
};

// is this not infinitely circular?
const X A<int>::a = X(A<float>::a.x + 1);
const X A<float>::a = X(A<int>::a.x + 1);

int main() {
    // error as expected, A<bool>::a cannot be default-constructed
    // cout << A<bool>::a.x << endl; 

    // this compiles and prints "1 2"
    cout << A<int>::a.x << " " << A<float>::a.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would have expected the two specialized definitions of `a` to generate a compiler error, since they are both initialized using the value of the other, and there isn't even a default constructor to fall back on. But apparently, this compiles in ideone and prints `1 2`. So how did the compiler arrive to the conclusion that the two instances of `X` should be initialized with these values?

Comment: No, it's not, it's undefined behaviour.
A<float>::a hasn't been assigned before A<int>:a, meaning you're just reading random memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That just happens to be a side effect of the initialization of non-local variables. The standard says:

> 3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.init]
>
> ...
> ... Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5)
>   before any other initialization takes place...
> ... Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.
>   Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an
>   implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered [ Note: an explicitly specialized
>   static data member or variable template specialization has ordered initialization. —end note ] Variables
>   with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their
>   definitions in the translation unit.

That's exactly what happens here:

- `A<int>::a` and `A<float>::a` are both 0 initialized
- they are then initialized in the order of their definitions

  - first `A<int>::a` reads what lies in `A<float>::a` which is 0 because of the previous 0 initialization, adds 1 and is fully initialized with 1
  - then `A<float>::a` gets the value of the now fully initialized `A<int>::a` which is 1, adds 1 and is fully initialized with 2

That means that this is a well formed program.

But same paragraph says later:

> if the initialization of an object obj1 refers to an object obj2 of namespace scope
>   potentially requiring dynamic initialization and defined later in the same translation unit, it is unspecified
>   whether the value of obj2 used will be the value of the fully initialized obj2 (because obj2 was statically
>   initialized) or will be the value of obj2 merely zero-initialized

So I am unsure whether the output is required to be 1 2, or whether it could be 2, 1 if the dynamic initialization of `A<int>::a` first triggers the dynamic initialization of `A<float>::a`